# soapui SOAP request empty

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am using sopaui to simulates a soap call. I got below WSDL file frmo my team. I clicked in "SOAP" icon and selected the wsdl file from my desktop. After that i clicked on Request 1 and I see below empty request

[![soapui request][1]][1]

Below is the WSDL content. anything wrong in WSDL file? I have removed lot of content from WSDL as it exceeds length restrictions of question

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:messages">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="ARBCIG_ORDERS">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="IDOC" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:complexType name="ARBCIG_ORDERS.E1CUCFG">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>CU: Configuration data</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="POSEX" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Character field of length 6</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="CONFIG_ID" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Character field of length 6</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="ROOT_ID" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Character field, 8 characters long</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="8"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="SCE" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>CU: Only Information Transferred from SCE to Configuration</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="KBNAME" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Knowledge-Base Object</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="KBVERSION" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Runtime Version of SCE Knowledge Base</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="COMPLETE" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>General Indicator</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="CONSISTENT" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>General Indicator</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="CFGINFO" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>CU: Configuration BLOB (SCE)</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="250"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="KBPROFILE" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Knowledge-Base Profile</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="KBLANGUAGE" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Configuration Language</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="CBASE_ID" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Instance Number (Persistent)</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="32"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="CBASE_ID_TYPE" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:documentation>Type of Instance Number (Persistent)</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="SEGMENT" type="xsd:string" fixed="1" use="required"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS">
    <wsdl:part name="idoc" element="ARBCIG_ORDERS"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS.PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS">
      <wsdl:input message="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding xmlns:idoc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:idoc:messages" name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS.PortTypeBinding" type="idoc:ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS.PortType">
    <soap:binding xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="ORDERS.ARBCIG_ORDERS">
      <soap:operation xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

working case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="SendOrder_Async"
    targetNamespace="http://cpi.sap.com/demo" xmlns:p1="http://cpi.sap.com/demo"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:documentation />
    <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true" />
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_SendOrder_Async" />
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://cpi.sap.com/demo"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://cpi.sap.com/demo">
            <xsd:element name="Order_MT" type="Order_DT" />
            <xsd:complexType name="Order_DT">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="orderNumber" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="customerName" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="orderAmount" type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="taxAmount" type="xsd:decimal" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="Order_MT">
        <wsdl:documentation />
        <wsdl:part name="Order_MT" element="p1:Order_MT" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SendOrder_Async">
        <wsdl:documentation />
        <wsdl:operation name="SendOrder_Async">
            <wsdl:documentation />
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_SendOrder_Async" />
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:Order_MT" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SendOrder_AsyncBinding" type="p1:SendOrder_Async">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SendOrder_Async">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I believe that is an XSD for the WSDL, not the endpoint definition itself.

Comment: i have used another WSDL and it works fine. I have added it the original post. I cannot figure out what is the differene @ou_ryperd

Comment: At cursory comparison it looks fine. Can you ask them to deploy it and let SoapUI get it from the server ? If there are problems it may be found during deployment.

Comment: You mean use the URL of WSDL location instead of WSDL file? unfortunately that is not possible, it is not publicly accessible

Comment: Can you not access it? How are you goung to test it then?